# how to implement a date range in accessing firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

how can I implement a date range when accessing firebase?

here is my query:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> readHistoryIncomeStream() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Income')
        .where('idUser', isEqualTo: _idUser)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One Idea isto store timeStamp in your firebase collection .
Now after getting timeStamp from snapshots you can format it to time . and get your result

Comment: I have a timestamp in the collection

Comment: so now get all your timestamp data in a list  of formatted time